# How to create bootstrap 5 tabs in nextjs?

Tags: next.js, bootstrap-5

I have install bootstrap and import import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' in my _app.js
But after creating the tabs it does not work can someone help please?

**Here is the tab code**

```
import Link from 'next/link'

const NavigationTabs = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <nav>
                <div
                    className='nav nav-tabs mb-3 justify-content-center'
                    id='tabContentList'
                    role='tablist'
                >
                    <Link href='#login' className='nav-item'>
                        <a
                            className='nav-link active'
                            id='nav-login-tab'
                            role='tab'
                            data-bs-toggle='tab'
                            data-bs-target='#login'
                            aria-controls='login'
                            aria-selected='true'
                        >
                            Login
                        </a>
                    </Link>
                    <Link href='#register' className='nav-item'>
                        <a
                            className='nav-link active'
                            id='nav-register-tab'
                            data-bs-toggle='tab'
                            data-bs-target='#register'
                            role='tab'
                            aria-controls='register'
                            aria-selected='false'
                        >
                            Register
                        </a>
                    </Link>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div className='tab-content' id='nav-tabContent'>
                <div
                    className='tab-pane fade show active'
                    id='login'
                    role='tabpanel'
                    aria-labelledby='nav-login-tab'
                >
                    Tab 1 content
                </div>
                <div
                    className='tab-pane fade'
                    id='register'
                    role='tabpanel'
                    aria-labelledby='nav-register-tab'
                >
                    Tab 2 content
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default NavigationTabs
```

Is there a better way to create it in bootstrap 5 or should I add the script tag from bootstrap?

Comment: You need to use some library like [`react-bootstrap`](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app) to make this work. Or inject the proper bootstrap scripts in head. Importing just CSS doesn't work with interactive elements.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try.

Comment: I just install react-bootstrap and use the tabs model and BOOM! It works. thank you again. @brc-dd